# Connecting Cloud Run with Memorystore for redis

Tags: serverless, google-cloud-run

I am trying to connect cloud run to memorystore for redis in the same region. I have a question regarding the serverless VPC access connector I have to create.

1. Do I need to set it to 10.8.0.0/28 or I can use another subnet?
2. The documentation is very unclear on how the I will be charged for the VPC connector. It says that the VPC connector is actually a few VMs handling the traffic, but egress charge is something which is not clear from the documentation. As one request is two way communication CR -> VM -> Redis and then Redis -> VM -> CR, will I be charged for both egress from Cloud Run to the connector (CR -> VM). As somewhere in the doc it says that "Egress to a connector from a serverless resource such as a function, app, or service is not charged.".

I am trying to connect cloud run to memorystore for redis in the same region. I have a question regarding the serverless VPC access connector I have to create.